# BB10 Cordova, <img ng-src=""> images not loading

Tags: angularjs, cordova, blackberry-10

I have BB10 cordova app,
In view I have

```
<img ng-src="{{'someImageLink'}}">
```

And some local images not showing, there is blue question mark.
But if I will change to

```
<img src="someImageLink">
```

img works perfectly

Changing to

```
<img src="{{'someImageLink'}}">
```

not helping at all

Can't diagnose, do you mby have any ideas or know how to fix this issue on BB10?

Comment: It actually almost sounds like the angular.js files aren't being loaded.. You could also make a build with Web Inspector to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You're close!  Since Angular already evaluates the contents of ng-src, you do not need to wrap your expression in {{ }} braces:

```
$scope.imageLink = "image.png";

<img ng-src="imageLink">
```

After being evaluated, this will leave you with the equivalent of this, in the DOM:

```
<img src="image.png">
```

If you're using a hardcoded string to a local image file, and it will never ever change in your app, there's nothing wrong with using `src="image.png"` directly.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I will check if it works abit later, for now I had to whiteListe images using $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist('/'); Because angular was adding "safe"